# Goで、IE11のキャッシュを消したいです。

Tags: go

GoでIE11のキャッシュを消去したいのですが、以下の事を試してみましたが、駄目でした。

"github.com/patrickmn/go-cache"のライブラリーを利用し、

```
c.Flush()
```

でのキャッシュの削除

もう一つは"os/exec"のライブラリーを利用して、

```
out, err := exec.Command("cmd","RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8").Output()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

go-cacheでは、上手くキャッシュが削除できませんでした。
execの方では、

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\project\�ۑ�����\Go>
```

と文字化けしてしまい、上手く実行できません。
直接、Dosプロンプトで"RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8"で実行するとキャッシュが削除することは確認が取れています。
また、ショートカットを作成して、RunDll32.exe.likで実行しようとも試みましたが、駄目でした。

宜しければ、ご教示お願い致します。

Comment: `"cmd"`ではなくて`"RunDll32.exe"`を実行プログラムとして指定してみては？ [コマンドラインを使用して Internet Explorer キャッシュをクリアする方法](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/internet-explorer/kb-support/clear-ie-cache-from-command-line) あるいは管理者として実行が指定出来れば試してみるとか？

Comment: @kunif アドバイスありがとうございます。アドバイスを参考に試してみましたが、駄目でした。javaScriptの方で、キャッシュの削除をすることで解決に至りました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goでは駄目でしたので、javaScript側でのキャッシュの削除で対応しました。

```
document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', 'false');
```

今回は、IE11の条件でhtmlのメタ属性

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

を試しても駄目だったのでプログラムの方で対処した次第になります。